# OnItemSelectedListener of ListView is not getting envoked

Tags: android, android-listview, listener

I have a list view and using two listeners - OnItemClicked and OnItemSelected. The clicked listener is working properly but onItemSelected Listener is not getting invoked. I need OnItemSelected listener because sometimes selected is set pragmatically.

```
         allClues.post(new Runnable() {            
            public void run() {
            listView.setSelection(ind);

                }
            });
```

I am expecting that when  selection is set its OnSelection listener will be  invoked. But its not happening.

```
  listView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             iSelected = arg2 ;

            Log.e("listargs", (String.valueOf(arg1)) + " " + String.valueOf(arg3));
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

What could be wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

`OnItemSelectedListener` is used for the `Spinner` not for the `Listview` For `Listview` you have to use `OnItemClickListener`

Answer (score 0):

**You have to use  OnItemClickListener like this**

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int i,
                long j) {
            // do ur code

        }
    });
```